# Extract audio from a video blob with vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web, audio, video

On a web page, after recording screen video and audio using `navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia` and a `MediaRecorder`, I end up with a video blob. How can I extract using only vanilla JavaScript on the client the audio from that blob and for example have it downloaded to the user?
I'm simply looking for this function:

```js
async function extractAudio(videoBlob) {
  // ...

  return audioBlob;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work with the [video-to-audio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/video-to-audio) npm package. It wasn't working at first but now it's all good.